# split the string into array using regular expression in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I am trying to split the string and place in an array using regular expression.
The string may change every time
What I need to do is if the string match with T: then i need to get `4774 4848`
If the string matches both T: and M:, then I need my result as

```
array(
[0] => 4774 4848, 
[1]=>0448 888 899
)
```

This is my code,

```
if (preg_match("/[T:|M:|Mob:|Phone:]\W(.*)[\W:]/mi", "T: 4774 4848 M: 0448 888 899", $matches))
        print_r($matches);
```

Here my output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => T: 4774 4848 M: 0448 888 
    [1] =>  4774 4848 M: 0448 888
)
```

How can I split `[1] =>  4774 4848 M: 0448 888` as

```
[1] => 4774 4848, 
[2]=>0448 888 899
```

Please help me in getting this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Square brackets `[..]` mean a character class, not alternative. You'd also want to use `preg_match_all`, something more specific + less greedy than `(.*)`, and not consume the trailing `\W:`.

Comment: can you please give me a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do matching instead of splitting. Use preg_match_all to do a global match.

```
preg_match_all("/(?:[TM]:|Mob:|Phone:)\s*\K.*?(?=\s*[A-Z]:|$)/mi", "T: 4774 4848 M: 0448 888 899", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4774 4848
            [1] => 0448 888 899
        )

)
```

Input with `T:` only,

```
preg_match_all("/(?:[TM]:|Mob:|Phone:)\s*\K.*?(?=\s*[A-Z]:|$)/mi", "T: 4774 4848", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4774 4848
        )

)
```